# How do I show the name of a user in my mapping table instead of his ID?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, rdbms

I have a User-Role Many-To-Many-Relationship in my MySQL database. Therefore I have a mapping-table which connects the IDs of both tables. The **mapping-table** looks like that:

```
ID of User | ID of Role
---------- | ----------
1          | 1
1          | 2
2          | 1
2          | 3
```

**user-table:**

```
Firstname of User | ID of User
----------------- | ----------
ExampleUser1      | 1
ExampleUser2      | 2
```

**role-table:**

```
Name of Role      | ID of Role
----------------- | ----------------
ExampleRole1      | 1
ExampleRole2      | 2
ExampleRole3      | 3
```

and I want my **mapping-table** to look like this:

```
Firstname of User | Name of Role
----------------- | ------------
ExampleUser1      | ExampleRole1
ExampleUser1      | ExampleRole2
ExampleUser2      | ExampleRole1
ExampleUser2      | ExampleRole3
```

What is the SQL-Query to realize that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with joins

```
select user.user_name, roles.role_name from mapping_table 
inner join user on user.id = mapping_table.user_id
inner join roles on role.id = mapping_table.role.id
```

Comment: but my mapping table only has the id of user and role so user_name or role_name doesnt work

Comment: Name of user and role will be present user and role table respectively. I have updated the code for you, please change the field name accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You need to join all three tables, and use the mapping tables to replace IDs with names:

```
SELECT u.name, r.name
FROM   user u
JOIN   user_role ur ON u.id = ur.user_id
JOIN   role r ON r.id = ur.role_id
```